# It is correct if the submenu will appear on click, and disappears if I click again on the same item or another item?

Tags: menu, drop-down-list

I have three possibilities:

A) submenu appears all'hover (and then disappears if you move the mouse)

B) the menu appears to the click, but disappears when you move the mouse from the item clicked or submenu

C) the submenu will appear on click, and disappears if I click again on the same item or another item

I would prefer to use the third option, but I'm not sure which one is the best option. Is there a proper convention?

Answer (score 1):

@Eric what do you think about this article:

http://uxmovement.com/navigation/why-hover-menus-do-users-more-harm-than-good/ ??

said that there are problems if use dropmenu with hover

Comment: If you can, please copy and paste the relevant sections of the article into your post. Links fade and rot after a while.

Answer (score 1):

### I would go with Option C

All **primary** content and functions of a page should be visible without a user having to do anything as soon as the page loads (with the exception of maybe having to scroll vertically on smaller screens)

What you describe in Option C sounds like a `toggle` pattern and is very common. If you have menu items providing **secondary** navigation or a list of advance options which most people won't use then showing/hiding those secondary items with a single click is the way to go since this will work on devices that don't have a concept of hover.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a combination of B and C. On a desktop or laptop with a mouse, the hover works well, but on a mobile device (or any touch enabled device) you need to support clicking (since there is no concept of hovering).